# How to get the password and username from odbc.ini elegantly in Perl

Tags: perl, odbc, dbi

ODBC driver api has a function SQLGetPrivateProfileString in C/C++.I can use it to get the username and password from odbc.ini and connect to db.

But for perl DBI module, there are not any functions like this, I have to read the file directly and it's not recommended.
Is there any good solution? Thanks.

Comment: I would happily accept a patch to add a call to SQLGetPrivateProfileString to DBD::ODBC but I've never come across anyone asking this before. What is your usage case?

Comment: My purpose is to make the perl script read the same configuration file as C++ code.

Comment: With all respect that is just another way of saying what you originally said. If you told me why you think you need to read the odbc.ini entries I might be able to think of another way of doing what you are trying to do without adding support for SQLGetPrivateProfileString (which would take me considerably longer than 5 minutes).

Comment: In C++ code, SQLGetPrivateProfileString is called to get the username and password and then is used to connect db. In perl script, I also need to read odbc.ini like what SQLGetPrivateProfileSting does in C++ code.I must provide username and password in DBI->connect.However, there is not a good way to get  the username and password.

Comment: You don't have to provide user/pass in DBI's connect, you can omit them.